Gayatri mantras for Hindu deities
What are the authentic Gayatri mantras for maa sarswati , Ganesha Kartikeya , maa Kali . From which texts do these come from?

There is only one gayatri mantra. That is from the vedas. There is no gayatri mantra for different deities.

But in the Internet there are many Gayatri mantras for different deities.

I can provide the scriptural source of the gayatri mantra from the vedas. But those internet gayatri mantras do not have source. Do they?

Exactly @AmritenduMukhopadhyay, that is why I wanted to ask this question .

@AmritenduMukhopadhyay Apart from the Vaidika Gayatri, there are indeed multiple Gayatris for different deities, which are actually Tantrika in nature. Shivagayatri is for the adherents of Shaiva agamas like Shaiva siddhanta & Trika, while Vishnugayatri is for the adherents of Vaishnava agamas like the Pancharatra. Tantrika nibandhas mention these various Tantrika gayatri  mantras. Still I would agree with you that the specimen taken randomly from the internet are highly unreliable.

Thank you @অনু.

The Gāyatrī mantras of Sarasvatī, Gaṇeśa, Kārtikeya (Ṣaṇmukha), Kāli, and several other devatās, can be found in Gāyatrī tantra section of Mantramahārṇava https://archive.org/details/mantra-maharnava-khemraj-publishers/page/n13/mode/2up?view=theater  These are generally tāntrīki and not Vaidika, as @অনু said, and please don't randomly recite (or chant) them without adhikāra, otherwise you would commit pāpa. Where do all these Gāyatrī mantras come from in this tāntrikīnibandha Mantramahārṇava? Well, they are collated from several tantraśāstras, some might be from Veda too.

This kind of monkey business suits Tantriks ~ @AmritenduMukhopadhyay
Please don't disrespect the entire tāntrikī paramparā and tantraśāstras.

There is only one Gayatri mantra. That is from the Vedas. There is no Gayatri mantra for different deities. The Gayatri Mantra is dedicated to the Sun God.
Here is the scriptural source of the Gayatri mantra from the Vedas. I am quoting from Sukla Yajurveda. The same Mantra is found in other Vedas as well (Rigveda 3.62.10, Samaveda Mantra Number 1462 [placed in Uttararchika, Chapter 13])

(Savita Devata, Vishvamitra Rishi)


tatsaviturvareṇyam bhargo devasya dhīmahi.
dhiyo yo naḥ pracodayāt.


May we attain that excellent glory of Savitar the God: So may he stimulate our prayers. - ||Shukla Yajurveda 3.35||

